# C++ - RegCreateKeyEx success but without result

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Could anybody tell me what's wrong is with this code? There is no errors. Everything returns ERROR_SUCCESS but in register can't see any changes.

```
void Utils::writePath(LPCTSTR data)
{
    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    if(RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
      TEXT("SOFTWARE\\aaTestCompany\\testApp"), 
      0, NULL, 0, 
      KEY_WRITE, NULL, 
      &hkey, &dwDisposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
    {
        long setRes = RegSetValueEx (hkey, "testPath", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, strlen(data)+1);
         if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                printf("Success writing to Registry.");
            } else {
                printf("Error writing to Registry.");
            }
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
    }
    else
        MessageBox(NULL,"error","",0);
}
```

Comment: Is it a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: Yup, this is 32-bit app on 64-bit OS. Is it important?

Comment: LPCTSTR = Long Pointer to a constant string -it's a free FYI

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869783/588306).

Comment: possible duplicate of [I added a registry key, but I cannot find it programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363768/i-added-a-registry-key-but-i-cannot-find-it-programmatically)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the application is 32-bit on a 64-bit OS the registry key will actually be created beneath `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`.

See [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Amazing how many people don't read/know this. It's asked several times a week in many places online.

Comment: @Deanna: Not everybody is expert in everything ;)

Comment: What should be done to set the key under the actual specified path?

Comment: @user1198065 Just read the documentation. The page pointed to by the link [hmjd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1033896) posted references [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx) which offers exactly the information you are looking for. The same information can already be found on [Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724878.aspx). Hint: `KEY_WOW64_64KEY`/`KEY_WOW64_32KEY`

Comment: In my case the CLSID's were being registered at HKLM\Wow6432Node (no SOFTWARE path).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with 5th and 6th parameters as REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS