# RegSetValueEx returning ERROR_SUCCESS but no value shows up

Tags: c, windows, winapi, registry

I'm trying to set a registry value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` to make my application run on startup. The following function is returning `TRUE`, but the value isn't showing up.

```
BOOL InstallRunOnStartup(const char* applicationName)
{
  HKEY key;
  char filePath[MAX_PATH];
  long result;
  BOOL ret = FALSE;

  result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0L, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key); 
  if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    if (GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, filePath, MAX_PATH) != 0)
      if (RegSetValueEx(key, applicationName, 0, REG_SZ, filePath, strlen(filePath) + 1) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        ret = TRUE;
    RegCloseKey(key);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say 'showing up' do you mean it's not appearing in regedit? If you're a 32-bit program on a 64-bit OS you'll be redirected to the Wow6432Node registry key.

Comment: Wow, it's there. Ok, if you post an answer I'll upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, since you are using `char*`, `char[]` and `GetModuleFileNameA()` to work with Ansi data, you should be using `RegSetValueExA()` to match that encoding. Your code compiles as-is only because `UNICODE` is not defined so `RegOpenKeyEx()` maps to `RegOpenKeyExA()` and `RegSetValueEx()` maps to `RegSetValueExA()`. If you ever enable Unicode, your code will not compile as-is anymore. If you want to work with Ansi but support Unicode in the future, use `TCHAR[]` and `GetModuleFileName()` instead, and `TEXT()` to wrap literals, so they match the encoding used by `RegSetValueEx()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ - RegCreateKeyEx success but without result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585286/c-regcreatekeyex-success-but-without-result)

Comment: The close notice is misleading.  It says it was closed as "too localized" when actually it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program is 32 bit and running on a 64-bit OS, your access to HKLM\SOFTWARE will be redirected to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node. There's more info about this on MSDN: [32-bit and 64-bit Application Data in the Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Also of note is the (as I understand it) unnecessary / potentially problematic, use of `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`. Read more here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/-ZZ-KYqZ70s/NAGy1wACcBcJ