# Access unknown folder in a Batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, directory

I need to specify my Java folder in order to use Sikuli.
Problem is: The folder has different names depending on its version

How can I use
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe`
in a batch file without knowing the `jre1.8.0_60` part.
I need some kind of wildcard.
In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\` is only the folder I need.

I hope it is clear what I am searching for. Couldn't find anything with google cause I am not sure how it is called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26912143/2861476) could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `%JAVA_HOME%` isn't defined on my machine.  If not on yours either, or if you don't want to depend on it, you could search `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\java` recursively for `java.exe` with the highest creation date.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: find newest java.exe
<NUL set /P "=Searching for Java executable... "
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\java\*java.exe"') do (
    set "jtest=%%I"
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%a in (
        'wmic datafile where "name='!jtest:\=\\!'" get CreationDate /format:list ^| find "="'
    ) do (
        set "created_test=%%a"
        set "created_test=!created_test:~0,-4!"
    )
    if not defined created (
        set "javaexe=!jtest!"
        set "created=!created_test!"
    ) else if !created_test! gtr !created! (
        set "javaexe=!jtest!"
        set "created=!created_test!"
    )
)

if not defined javaexe (
    echo Not found.  Is Java installed?
    goto :EOF
) else (
    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion & echo Found! & endlocal
    echo !javaexe!
    echo Relax and enjoy the show.
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
I don't understand your code very well since my skills are below basic but it worked perfectly.
I used !javaexe! for further actions.

Now I am curious, why Sikuli doesnt search Java like this.

Answer (score 2):

The java home directory is usually set in the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`.

So you should be able to use:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
```

(Use `"` to prevent problems with spaces in the path)

Comment: I guess JAVA_HOME isn't defined on my machine. Is this supposed to be definied as soon as I install Java?